# Cut off trailing group with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a couple of strings which all terminate with some numerical digits, immediately preceeded by a number of non-numerical characters, e.g., `10.1002/0470868279-ch1`. I would like cut off exactly this group; for this example `-ch1`. I tried

```
import re

str0 = '10.1002/0470868279-ch1'

a = re.match('(.*)([^0-9]+[0-9]*)', str0)
print(a.group(0))
print(a.group(1))
print(a.group(2))

str1 = '10.1002/0470868279.1'  # likewise
```

but that's not quite it:

```
10.1002/0470868279.ch1
10.1002/0470868279.c
h1
```

I guess the regex matches greedily from the start.

Any hints?

Comment: Use [`re.sub(r'\W+\w+$','',str0)`](http://ideone.com/PL39FG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `?` to make first match non-greedy so it matches as little as possible. Also add `$` so that match will always go to end of string:

```
a = re.match('(.*?)([^0-9]+[0-9]*)$', str0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should match up to the end of what you want: `(-|\+)?\d+(\.\d*)?/(-|\+)?\d+(\.\d*)?` This would let you extract the numbers you are looking for.

This pattern would match just the end portion (*tested on your `-ch1` example*): `(?<=\d)[^\d\./][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

I'm not really sure what you mean by "cut off", seeing as your example is just pulling out groups and not actually manipulating the string to cut anything off, but either of those patterns should extract the portions you are looking for.